# Has anyone tried using the Firebase javascript library from within Dart?

Tags: dart, firebase

The [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com) key-value store looks intriguing, and would be fun to use with Dart's HTML framework.

They offer a JavaScript library for reading/writing to their model. Has anyone tried using it with Dart?

My plan (based on very little Dart knowledge) is to:

- Include their library in my html
- Load the js.dart package
- instantiate a model through js.dart
- read and write through model.

Does that seem like the right approach?  Or, is there a much better way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: [Firebase founder here] I'm not aware of anyone trying this to date, but I'd love to see it work. If you get an implementation working, please let us know!

Comment: hi Andy, were you able to get this going?  I'm looking at doing the same thing for a personal project.

Comment: Funny you should ask. I have just come back to look at Dart. There is so much to like about it. I just wish it were actually Smalltalk ;-) Anyway, the short answer is 'no', but some of the info at the bottom of the thread looks promising.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any Javascript library through the [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js).

For [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com/) you have to :

- add the [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) to your `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  js: any
```

- add the the following `<script>` to your html page :

```html
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="youDartCode.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
```

- use [Firebase Javascript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/index.html) through [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js). Something like :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  final myDataRef = new js.Proxy(js.context.Firebase,
      'https://xxx.firebaseio-demo.com/');
  myDataRef.on('child_added', (snapshot, String previousChildName) {
    final message = snapshot.val();
    print("${message.name} : ${message.text}");
  });
  myDataRef.push(js.map({"name": 'myName', "text": 'js interop rocks'}));
}
```

The above Dart code is the equivalent of the following JavaScript code :

```js
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://xxx.firebaseio-demo.com/');
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot, previousChildName) {
  var message = snapshot.val();
  console.log(message.name + " : " + message.text);
}));
myDataRef.push({name: 'myName', text: 'js interop rocks'});
```

---

Basically :

- when you have to instantiate a Javascript object, use `new js.Proxy(js.context.MyJavascriptObjectName, arg1, arg2, arg3))`,
- when you have to provide a Javascript anonymous object, use `js.map({'attr1', value1}, {'attr2', value2})`.

Comment: A lot of time has passed since this initial thread. There is now a firebase package in pub:  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase

Comment: The syntax for interacting with javascript interop has changed in more recent versions of dart.  This example won't work with Firebase 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

There's now a wrapper for the firebase.js library in Dart here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart/ (also available on pub). It uses dart:js as discussed in this thread, so inclusion of firebase.js is still required!

Answer (score 0):

I got the error message "Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: ReceivePortSync is not defined" when Dart got to here.

```
    js.scoped (() {

    });
```

An additional line of code is needed to use Firebase with Dart.  Add the line  "packages/browser/interop.js"

```
    <script type="application/dart" src="ScrollViewDemo.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>   
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
```

----------------- Edit Aug 15 ----------

```
js.scoped is no longer needed in the newer version of interopt.js
```

Comment: The _js_ package introduced `interop.js` after I submitted my answer. I have updated it. Thanks.