# How to use Google Dart with Firebase Simple login (pass function inside function)

Tags: javascript, dart, firebase

Has anybody figured out how to use the Firebase Simple Login with Google Dart? I am trying to figure out how to define function(error, user){} when calling FirebaseSimpleLogin. Both error and user() are objects.

This is the sample javascript code from Firebase

```
   var myDataRef = new js.Proxy(js.context.Firebase, 'https://johnstest1.firebaseIO.com/');
    var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://johnstest1.firebaseIO.com/');
    var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myDataRef, function(error, user) {
      if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
      } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
      } else {
        // user is logged out
      }
    });
```

This is the code added to the html file for use by both Dart and Firebase

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>  
    <script type="application/dart" src="firebasetestlogin.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
```

In the .dart file the javascript library has been imported using pubspec.yaml

```
   import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
```

In the main() this line of code works fine and I am able to write data to the database. The line that is commented out is the original javascript line while the next line is the Dart version and it works.

```
    js.scoped((){
        // var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://johnstest1.firebaseio.com');
        var myDataRef = new js.Proxy(js.context.Firebase, 'https://johnstest1.firebaseIO.com/');  
    });
```

This is the same code from main with the line for Firebase Simple Login Added.  I have been trying to figure out how to write the code for function(error, user).

```
  js.scoped((){
        // var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://johnstest1.firebaseio.com');
        var myDataRef = new js.Proxy(js.context.Firebase, 'https://johnstest1.firebaseIO.com/');  

       //var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(js.context.Firebase(myDataRef, function(error, user){}{}));   
       var auth = new js.Proxy(js.context.FirebaseSimpleLogin(myDataRef, js.context.function(error, user)));

  });
```

Comment: There was a question earlier about using Firebase with Dart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904486/has-anyone-tried-using-the-firebase-javascript-library-from-within-dart - perhaps the answer there will help?

Comment: This was more complicated than the question on the other post and I wasn't sure if I should add a second question to the original post or create a new topic. I saw a post where people got mad at somebody for asking a second question on the same post. The part about passing a function inside a function made it a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use Dart callback functions in Js you have to create a [Callback](http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js/Callback.html) and use it as paramter.

The dart equivalent of your first pasted js code is :

```dart
var myDataRef = new js.Proxy(js.context.Firebase, 
    'https://johnstest1.firebaseIO.com/');
var auth = new js.Proxy(js.context.FirebaseSimpleLogin, myDataRef, 
    new js.Callback.many((error, user) {
      if (error != null) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        window.console.log(error);
      } else if (user != null) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        window.console.log('User ID: ${user.id}, Provider: ${user.provider}');
      } else {
        // user is logged out
      }
    }));
```

Note : you can avoid `js.scoped` that is not needed since few versions of [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js).

Comment: I am getting the error message "Breaking on exception: null" when it gets to the if (error) statement. Are there any additional packages that need to be installed since I currently have (browser, js and meta) installed.?

Comment: You get this error because `error` is `null`. I updated the answer with `if (error != null)` (I haven't read the Firebase API and didn't know what `error` was).

Answer (score 3):

This is some sample code to use Dart to log into Firebase. This combines the answers from Alexandre Ardhuin into one post with some additional code.

The example will:

- Get firebase reference and checks to see if user is online
- Create a new Firebase user using email and password login
- Login into Firebase
- Adds a child_added listener and prints any data in the database to the console
- Push some data to Firebase and trugger the child_added to display data.
- Logout of Firebase

Add the js package http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js to your program

Add these three lines to the HTML file.

```
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>     
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
```

- Put this code in the .dart file.

  ```
  var YOUR_FIREBASE_PATH = 'https://johnstest1.firebaseIO.com/';
  var emailAddress = "emailAddress@xyz.com";
  var password = "password";

  var myDataRef = new js.Proxy(js.context.Firebase, YOUR_FIREBASE_PATH);

  // Firebase 
  var auth = new js.Proxy(js.context.FirebaseSimpleLogin, myDataRef, 
    new js.Callback.many((error, user) {
      if (error != null) {
      window.console.log("Firebase login returned a null");         
      // an error occurred while attempting login
      window.console.log(error);
  } else if (user != null) {
      // user authenticated with Firebase
      window.console.log('User ID: ${user.id}, Provider: ${user.provider}');
  } else {
      window.console.log("User is logged out");
      // user is logged out
  }
  ```

  })
  );
- Create a new user using email and password to login

  ```
   // Create a new user using email and password
   auth.createUser(emailAddress, password, 
      new js.Callback.many((error, user) {
      if (error != null && user != null)
      {        
          if (!error) {
              window.console.log('User Id: ' + user.id + ', Email: ' + user.email);
          }
      } 
    })
  );
  ```
- Firebase login.

  ```
  // Login to firebase
  auth.login('password', js.map({'email': emailAddress, 'password': password}));
  ```

Add a child_added callback and if a new child gets added to the databes this will get called

```
    // Add a listener for for child_added and gets all the data
    myDataRef.on('child_added',
        new js.Callback.many((snapshot, String previousChildName) {
        try {        
            final message = snapshot.val();
            print("${message.name} : ${message.text}");
        }
        catch (e) {} 
    }));
```

- Push some data to Firebase and the child_added callback will print whatever is in the database to the console.

  ```
  // Push some data to Firebase
  myDataRef.push(js.map({"name": 'Mark', "text": 'Works with Dart test 2'}));
  ```
- Log user out of Firebase

  ```
  // Logout
  auth.logout();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a dart-team-initiated dart wrapper for Firebase : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase .

With the usage of Future, dart version is way awesomer than js version.