# What version of Firebase is https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I see some [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904486/has-anyone-tried-using-the-firebase-javascript-library-from-within-dart/14909739#14909739) that refer to an `v0` URL for the Firebase JavaScript client library.

```
https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js
```

But, the URLs in the [official documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) all contain specific version numbers like this:

```
https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.21/firebase.js
```

I diffed the contents and have verified that the `v0` URL does not refer to the more recent version. What version is it?

Answer (score 6):

Do not use the `v0` URL.

It's a deprecated URL that's frozen on a very old version of the client library. Specifically, it's frozen at [v1.0.6](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.21/firebase.js).

If you have code that's using it, upgrade as soon as you can. You're missing out on a lot of bug fixes and enhancements.